# Excel Matching and Max

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have fake sales data that I need to extract the max sale from each of the 4 countries (Canada, US, Spain, and Germany). Using if and then max inside only worked for Canada due to it having the max sale. How do I find the others?

Comment: Please provide sample data together with what you have already tried

Comment: Yeah, some example data would be nice.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Since you have not provide sample data along with the Question, therefore I've used some dummy data to solve the issue.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- The Dummy Sales data is in Range `A3:C14`.
- To get unique list of countries enter this 
  Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `A20`, finish with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$14,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$19:A19,$A$3:$A$14),0)),"")}`

- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `B20`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

`{=MAX(($A$3:$A$14=A20)*($C$3:$C$14))}`

**N.B.**

- *Consider **OPtion 2 as a bonus**, is an 
  optional part I've included to show the 
  method to get highest sales of Country for
  particular Product.*
- **You and other readers may ignore it.**
- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `B28`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  `{=MAX(IF($A$3:$A$14=A20,IF($B$3:$B$14=$B$26,$C$3:$C$14)))}`

**Note,** Cell `B26` has Product Name `P1` and you may replace it with other if want to get their highest sales.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*